# Attributes and XML Documentation for method/property

Tags: c#, wpf, syntax

When I want to have an attribute and XML documentation for a method/property - what is the correct order to write them above the method/property?

This sounds so trivial, but...

If I use:

```
/// <summary>
/// Something here
/// </summary>
[MyAttribute]
public void MyMethod() {}
```

Build is successful and ReSharper is "happy", but I don't see the documentation in IntelliSense for `MyClass.MyMethod`.

When I use:

```
[MyAttribute]
/// <summary>
/// Something here
/// </summary>
public void MyMethod() {}
```

Build is successful but ReSharper has a warning (*XML comment is not placed on a valid language element*), and I still don't see the documentation in IntelliSense for `MyClass.MyMethod`.

I've searched the internet and see only examples where attributes are used without documentation; or documentation without attributes.

Is there really no way to have attributes and XML documentation for the same method/property?

Info: WPF application, .NET 4.0, C#.

Comment: Visual Studio (or maybe resharper)? Just type three slashes /// above the method (or attribute) and it will autogenerate.

Comment: Forgot to add - VS2010. I've tried to write above the attribute (first case above) but it didn't generate documentation in IntelliSense. Other methods/properties in the same class without attributes show documentation as expected. :(

Comment: When both case do not show up in Intellisense then you have an unrelated problem to solve first.

Comment: @Henk - I was afraid of that. Do you have any pointers regarding where to start looking?

Comment: Do a rebuild, check for errors and warnings. Do you check Intellisense in the same assembly?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the first case,

```
/// <summary>
/// Something here
/// </summary>
[MyAttribute]
public void MyMethod() {}
```

Resharper likes it and it should give you *Something here* in  Intellisense. When it doesn't then there is another problem to solve.

Comment: Needed to restart my machine... Most wasted two hours in my life... Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for saving me some more hours of coding and searching +1